# R Shiny app won't upload file or display plot

Tags: r, shiny

Hoping someone can help!

I am trying to create an R shiny app that will allow me to upload a file as well as display plots in different tabs. My code for the file upload works when I don't introduce the tabs - not sure why this would affect anything.

I also can't seem to get my ggplot to display either, although the code works outside the shiny app.

Here is my current code (I know I have widgets that don't do anything yet...):

```
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel(h1("Title", align = "center")),

   # Upload file
   fileInput("upload", "Data file:", buttonLabel = "Select File", multiple = FALSE),
   tableOutput("files"), 
   hr(),

   # Tabs for Display Options
   tabsetPanel(
     tabPanel("Table 1", tableOutput("table")),
     tabPanel("Plot1", plotOutput("distPlot")),
     tabPanel("Table 2", tableOutput("table")),
     tabPanel("Plot 2",plotOutput("distPlot")),
     tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary"))
   ),

   # Sidebar with interactive widgets 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
      # Radio Buttons for Data Normalization
      radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Pick:"),
                   choices = list("1" = 1, "1" = 2), selected = 1),
         hr(),

      # Checkbox for whether outliers should be included
      checkboxInput("outliers", "Show outliers", FALSE)
      ),
      mainPanel(
         h1("test...")
      )
   )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output) {

  # You can access the value of the widget with input$file
  output$files <- renderTable(input$upload)

  # Distribution Plots
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(column1)) + geom_density(aes(y = ..count..), fill = "lightgray")
    print(p)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Dat is just a data frame with 104 values in each of 2 columns (one named "column1"). Not sure how to share that here, but can be anything really as long as I can get it to display.

Thanks!!

Comment: You have multiple `plotOutput` in your `ui` with the same name. Same with `tableOutput`. Take out the 2 additional `tabPanel` statements from `ui` and see if that helps. If you want additional `tabPanel`, then change the name.

Comment: Hello @Schuyler Metzger, to make it reproducible, could you provide a sample dataset in this way: `dataset <- data.frame(column1 = c(...), column2 = c(...), ...)` so we can help you. Be aware that the data could be any value, not necessarily the real values.

Comment: @Manu ```dat <- data.frame(column1 = c(75,76,100,500,72,73,74,75), column2 = c(75,76,100,500,72,73,74,75)```